# fish shell suggests commands in tmux

Tags: terminal, command-line, tmux

I use fish shell, it's has option "suggests commands", so it is works like in the next screenshot.

**Examle:**
You type command `git status`. In the next time when you type just `g` or `git` fish give you hint (like in the next screenshot), so you can press `ctrl+F` and you are getting full command `git status`(like tab arrow in other terminals).

[image: suggests commands in fish shell]

But when I use tmux, this option **doesn't work correct**. There are no hint like in first screenshot. For examle: when I type `git`, it should be give me hint `git status`(like in first screenshot), but there are no any hint, I just see what I type. But when I press `ctrl+F` I get full command `git status`

[image]

In ubuntu it's works fine.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Tyson update question, hope it became more understandable.

Comment: Does it work in Ubuntu if you use `tmux` there?

Comment: @patrix yes in Ubuntu it works.

Comment: The key point is whether it works **with tmux** on Ubuntu?

Comment: The key point is that it works with tmux on Unbuntu but not on OS X.Maybe problem in config, but I don't find any solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

I actually encountered this problem recently on Ubuntu. It happens when tmux can't determine the number of colors supported by the terminal and sets it 8. If I run `tmux -2`, 256 colors are set and the command suggestions work as expected.

I found a detailed explanation here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118806/tmux-term-and-256-colours-support

Comment: same issue, but didn't work for me :(